# optimizing scripts by using requirejs with loading jquery from cdn

Tags: jquery, requirejs, cdn, minify, r.js

main.js below

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: ".",
    shim: {
        p: ['jquery']
    },
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min',
        'p': 'p'
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'c'], function ($) {
    console.log($)
});
```

c.js below

```
define(['p'], function () {
    return {};
});
```

build.js below

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    optimize: "none",
    mainConfigFile: 'main.js'

})
```

p.js

```
$('body').html('p!');
```

Build command:

```
node path/to/r.js -o ./build.js
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="../app/libs/requirejs/require.js" data-main="main-built"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And I got the error when tried to open this file:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Is it possible to fix this problem?

Thanks!

**UDP1:** 
I added this to build.js, but it doesn't work

```
paths: {
        jquery: "empty:"
    }
```

Comment: After you add the ``paths`` config, does it fail in exactly the same way as before? Also, are you sure that you are using the new version of your built file? If you are testing using a browser that loads files right off your local filesystem you can run into caching issues. (Clearing your cache ensures you're loading the latest files.)

Comment: Yes, it fail exactly the same way as before. I used 2.1.9 version of r.js and requirejs. I used nginx for local http server and I cleared the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`"empty:"` path](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty) in your build config:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    optimize: "none",
    mainConfigFile: 'main.js',
    paths: {
        jquery: "empty:"
    }
})
```